# Export Remote Registry Key - Receiving ERROR: Invalid key name

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to export a registry key on a remote machine using the code:

```
Foreach ($server in $servers)
            {               
                $backupFolder = $global:backupFolder
                $serverName = $server
                $backupFile = $global:backupFolder + '\' + $scmRef + "_" + $server + "_" + $userId + ".reg"
                $registryEntry = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\South River Technologies\Titan FTP Server\Servers\2\Users\"

                Write-Host "Reg" $backupFile $registryEntry

                Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {   
                    Write-Host "Creating Backup Folder on"$Using:serverName
                    New-Item -Path $Using:backupFolder -type directory -Force
                    Write-Host "Folder creation complete on"$Using:serverName
                    reg export $Using:registryEntry $Using:backupFile
                    Write-Host "Registry exported successfully to" $Using:backupFile
                }
            }
```

I'm receiving the error message and not sure why

ERROR: Invalid key name.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: Invalid key name.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
+ PSComputerName        : FRUSVAFD01

Type "REG EXPORT /?" for usage.

The code above creates the relevant folder correctly but cannot find the key name despite it being there.  I've run locally as reg export HKLM:\SOFTWARE\South River Technologies\Titan FTP Server\Servers\2\Users\  C:\Users<username>\desktop\registryentry.reg and it runs correctly.

Any idea why this doesn't work remotely? I'm at my wits end and have wasted most of the day googling.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably a permissions issue. Try specifying a credential object with creds from a user that has admin permissions on the servers. (needed when doing stuff in the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE branch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code probably needs a cleanup, but i think the issue is the colon in the registry path.  Try changing this:

```
 $registryEntry = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\South River Technologies\Titan FTP Server\Servers\2\Users\"
```

to this

```
 $registryEntry = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\South River Technologies\Titan FTP Server\Servers\2\Users\"
```